# Spark custom monitoring for DAGs and event timelines

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to have my own monitoring in my streaming application for the DAGs and event timelines shown by Apache Spark UI.

Is there a way to get these metrics or any listener to fetch these information?

My motive is to show live progress of data flowing through stages for batches using the metrics. I have already explored **StreamingListener** and its implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find it here in the Documentation:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api

I have no expierence with the REST API. But it looks like you can write your own monitoring tool with it.

Comment: Thanks Simon. I have explored it and it gives no information on DAGs and event timelines.